# What type of attribute should I use for an Image in java?

Tags: java, image, javafx, fxml

I plan to make a javaFX gui for an app that I'm working on. I have a class which contains attributes of something and in these attributes i want an Image which can be displayed in an ImageView (javaFX). Which type should i use for the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the constructor [`ImageView(Image)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#ImageView%28javafx.scene.image.Image%29) I would say store them as an `Image`.